# How can I get the web3 contract address before confirming transaction in the browser or chrome extension?

Tags: blockchain, web3js, metamask, ethers.js

Let's say I want to buy an NFT and my Metamask popup opens asking me to confirm the transaction. There you can see the contract address... but how can I access this contract address (just retrieve the value, not change it :) ) programmatically using javascript in the browser or an extension?

Answer (score 0):

Hey for getting the contract address on your console just include this code in the .sol file  and also update the abi of the code .

```
    function get() view public returns(address ){
        return address(this);
    }
```

And in the frontend to intract with your smart contract and for getting  the result in the console include this in your index.js file

```
              contract.methods.get().call().then(function (resp){
               console.log(resp);
              });
```